# How do I get intellisense to work inside es6 classes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a class that extends React. Component like so:

```
class Main extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        flavor: string.isRequired, 
        iceCreamMap: object.isRequired,
        restUrl: string.isRequired,
        token: string.isRequired,
        username: string.isRequired
    };
}
```

I want the methods of Component.prototype to show up in intellisense but it is not working. It however will work when I do. `React.Component.prototype`.